# Where do I publish very large formulae related to my question?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, stackexchange

Recently I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538564/19661) at Math.SE that contained several formulae essential for the question to be understood. While investigating the problem further, I came up with several other very large formulae that might be interesting/useful for people trying to answer the question, so I would like to make them available to the question readers. But I do not want to add them directly to the question, because they would cause it to bloat too much. Ideally, I would create a separate page with these formulae and add a link to it from the question.

Is it possible to do this relying entirely on StackExchange capabilities? Or do I need to search for an external hosting supporting $\LaTeX$/[*MathJax*](http://www.mathjax.org)?

Comment: What about just write them in LaTeX, compile to PDF, and then include the pictures in your post? That way they can be resized down so the post looks ok and you can be sure the vastness of your formulae won't be disrupted by the fickleness of site rendering.

Comment: Not PDF. If the formulas are in machine-readable form, I can put them into my own CAS.  Since they are "very large" they are probably not intended to be read by a human.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it considered a good style to post formulae on Math.SE in a _Mathematica_ language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any reasonable way to add an "appendix" using SE architecture, but a link from [mathb.in](http://mathb.in/) in the comments ought to be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [texpaste](http://www.texpaste.com/) or [mathb.in](http://mathb.in) (as Alexander Gruber mentioned). I prefer the first one as they have an option to later on edit the note.

If you want something that includes also markdown support, you could try [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/). This is more time consuming to set up, but a very good markdown+mathjax editor/publisher.

Comment: stackedit.io is *great*! Thanks for that one!